# how to save stream as mp4 and play it?

Tags: streaming, mp4, live-streaming

I need to play a live stream of my computer screen with a play that knows only to play MP4 files 
any ideas for how to save the stream to MP4 file and play is in the player ?

Answer (score -1):

VLC is the only tool you need to capture your screen and save it to MP4 file. Then you can play it wherever you want.

Everything you want to do is well described here: http://www.howtogeek.com/120202/how-to-record-your-desktop-to-a-file-or-stream-it-over-the-internet-with-vlc/

You can also directly capture your screen and immediately stream it via multi/unicast stream.

Works great both on Nix and Win platforms.

Comment: please don't provide a link. Try to think of a reproducable example

Comment: this record my screen but i cant play the file while it records